# pyinstaller GLIBC_2.25 not found, however another script works

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I created an executable out of a simple Python script, using pyinstaller on Ubuntu 18.04, and tested it in a different computer (also with Ubutnu 18) and worked perfectly.

However when trying the same with a more complex script (more library imports) the executable fails in the other computer with the error

```
ImportError: /lob/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.25' not found
```

This can't be a Python incompatibility (see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4758), as the other script did work fine. So it most probably is based on some of the libraries the second script imports.

How can I include the libraries imported in the executable made by Pyinstaller (if that is even the origin of this error)?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A**

I have not confirmed this solution, but it sometimes helps. Delete directories ./build and ./dist, then try creating the executable again with pyinstaller.

**Solution B**

The solution, for me at least, is to build your executable on an older version of your OS.

I was seeing the same error.

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIjdcWu4/./libX11.so.6)
[32614] Failed to execute script 'test_executable' due to unhandled exception!
```

I built my exectuable with Pyinstaller on Ubuntu 22.04. Then I copied and ran the executable on the older Ubuntu 20.04 and the error was encountered.

Per the comment below, this might be a compatibility issue where the executable built on a newer OS is not compatible with older OSs.

> "For what is worth, the issue could be that the libraries bundled with
> the built program conflict with the system libraries, preventing the
> DRI driver from properly loading.
>
> The culprit could be either standard c/c++ libraries (libgcc_s.so.1,
> libstdc++.so.6) or maybe the X11 libraries (libX11.so.6, libXau.so.6,
> libXdmcp.so.6, libXext.so.6, `libXrender.so.1˙). Perhaps more likely
> former than the latter.
>
> For example, if libstdc++.so.6 on the build system is older than the
> one used by the target system, then the non-bundled libraries will
> fail to load due to missing symbols (which are present in the newer,
> system version of the library, but not in the bundled one). This is
> actually quite a common issue with binary-only software on linux,
> especially on more bleeding edge distributions. In those cases,
> removing the bundled version of the offending library may help.
>
> (You have a similar issue with system libgvfsdbus.so, which is missing
> a symbol that is not available in the bundled libglib-2.0.so.0, which
> is probably older than the glib library available on the system)."
> Source:
> https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop/issues/373#issuecomment-694476451